# Apache Flink - use values from a data stream to dynamically create a streaming data source

Tags: apache-flink

I'm trying to build a sample application using Apache Flink that does the following:

1. Reads a stream of stock symbols (e.g. 'CSCO', 'FB') from a Kafka queue.
2. For each symbol performs a real-time lookup of current prices and streams the values for downstream processing.

*** Update to original post ***

I moved the map function into a separate class and do not get the run-time error message "*The implementation of the MapFunction is not serializable any more. The object probably contains or references non serializable fields*".

The issue I'm facing now is that the Kafka topic "stockprices" I'm trying to write the prices to is not receiving them. I'm trying to trouble-shoot and will post any updates.

```
public class RetrieveStockPrices { 
    @SuppressWarnings("serial") 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment streamExecEnv = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        streamExecEnv.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.IngestionTime); 

        Properties properties = new Properties(); 
        properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092"); 
        properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181"); 
        properties.setProperty("group.id", "stocks"); 

        DataStream<String> streamOfStockSymbols = streamExecEnv.addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer08<String>("stocksymbol", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties)); 

        DataStream<String> stockPrice = 
            streamOfStockSymbols 
            //get unique keys 
            .keyBy(new KeySelector<String, String>() { 
                @Override 
                public String getKey(String trend) throws Exception {
                    return trend; 
                }
                }) 
            //collect events over a window 
            .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(60))) 
            //return the last event from the window...all elements are the same "Symbol" 
            .apply(new WindowFunction<String, String, String, TimeWindow>() {
                @Override 
                public void apply(String key, TimeWindow window, Iterable<String> input, Collector<String> out) throws Exception { 
                    out.collect(input.iterator().next().toString()); 
                }
            })
            .map(new StockSymbolToPriceMapFunction());

        streamExecEnv.execute("Retrieve Stock Prices"); 
    }
}

public class StockSymbolToPriceMapFunction extends RichMapFunction<String, String> {
    @Override
    public String map(String stockSymbol) throws Exception {
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment streamExecEnv = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        streamExecEnv.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.IngestionTime);
        System.out.println("StockSymbolToPriceMapFunction: stockSymbol: " + stockSymbol);

        DataStream<String> stockPrices = streamExecEnv.addSource(new LookupStockPrice(stockSymbol));
        stockPrices.keyBy(new CustomKeySelector()).addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer08<String>("localhost:9092", "stockprices", new SimpleStringSchema()));

        return "100000";
    }

    private static class CustomKeySelector implements KeySelector<String, String> {
        @Override
        public String getKey(String arg0) throws Exception {
            return arg0.trim();
        }
    }
}


public class LookupStockPrice extends RichSourceFunction<String> { 
    public String stockSymbol = null; 
    public boolean isRunning = true; 

    public LookupStockPrice(String inSymbol) { 
            stockSymbol = inSymbol; 
    } 

    @Override 
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception { 
            isRunning = true; 
    } 


    @Override 
    public void cancel() { 
            isRunning = false; 
    } 

    @Override 
    public void run(SourceFunction.SourceContext<String> ctx) 
                    throws Exception { 
            String stockPrice = "0";
            while (isRunning) { 
                //TODO: query Google Finance API 
                stockPrice = Integer.toString((new Random()).nextInt(100)+1);
                ctx.collect(stockPrice);
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`StreamExecutionEnvironment` are not indented to be used inside of operators of a streaming application. Not intended means, this is not tested and encouraged. It might work and do something, but will most likely not behave well and probably kill your application.

The `StockSymbolToPriceMapFunction` in your program specifies for each incoming record a completely new and independent new streaming application. However, since you do not call `streamExecEnv.execute()` the programs are not started and the `map` method returns without doing anything.

If you *would* call `streamExecEnv.execute()`, the function would start a new local Flink cluster in the workers JVM and start the application on this local Flink cluster. The local Flink instance will take a lot of the heap space and after a few clusters have been started, the worker will probably die due to an `OutOfMemoryError` which is not what you want to happen.

Comment: Is it at all possible to dynamically create streams in response to incoming data?

Comment: You can implement a `FlatMapFunction` that dynamically reads and emits data based on arriving records. For example, if you have a stream with file names, a `FlatMapFunction` you could open those files and emit their data. However, the output types of all records must be the same. Also, it might be challenging to get event-time processing semantics right, but that's more a general problem of dynamically added sources.

Comment: @FabianHueske I am solving a similar use case. So if i have to use FlatMapFunction then we will have to read the file using normal File API's from scala/Java and not using Flink's readTextFile. Reason being we cannot use StreamExecutionEnvironment inside flatMap. Is my understanding correct?