# RichSinkFunction for Cassandra in Flink

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I read the advantages of using `RichSinkFunction` over directly calling the DB methods. Therefore, I decided to write my own `RichSinkFunction`.

```
import org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.{RichSinkFunction, SinkFunction}
import com.datastax.driver.core.{Session, Cluster}

class CassandraAsSink extends RichSinkFunction {
  override def open(parameters: Configuration): Unit = {
    val cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("localhost").build()//
    val session = cluster.connect("example")
  }

  override def invoke(value: Nothing, context: SinkFunction.Context): Unit = {
    session.execute(
      s"""
  INSERT INTO users (name, credits, user_id)
  VALUES ($name, $credits, $userId)
  """
    )
  }

  override def close(): Unit = {
  //something like session.close()
  }

}
```

However, I am not able to develop it fully. I want to call this method under a separate class which should pass 3 arguments that I want to enter mentioned in the code. The record is in `JSON` format. I can manage that by parsing and getting the attributes. But how do I pass it to the `invoke` method and how can I pass the `session` object throughout the class. Also, is it a correct way of doing it since I am new to both Flink and Scala?

Will `stream/string.new CassandraAsSink().invoke(name,credits,user_id`) work when it comes to the calling part?

**`Modified:`**

```
class CassandraSink extends RichSinkFunction[String] {
  var cluster: Cluster = _
  var session: Session = _
  println("inside....")

  override def open(parameters: Configuration): Unit = {
    cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("localhost").build() //
    session = cluster.connect("example")
    println("Connected....")
  }

  override def invoke(value: String): Unit = {
    println("inside invoke: " + value)
    session.execute(
      s"""
  INSERT INTO jsondata1(records_b)
  VALUES ($value)
  """
    )
  }
override def close(): Unit = {
    session.close()
    println("Session Closed...")
    //something like session.close()
  }
}
```

`Calling part`:

```
val datastreamFromString:DataStream[String]=env.fromElements(data) // where data is string
        datastreamFromString.addSink(new CassandraAsSink())
```

I figured out that there is some problem with my `DataStream` created from `String`. The class is working fine. I have initialized the `env` variable as the second line in the class.

Comment: Here, Fabian has mentioned that we can't create `DataStream` in operators. So how can I achieve it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41210266/apache-flink-use-values-from-a-data-stream-to-dynamically-create-a-streaming-d

Answer (score 1):

Flink already has a [Cassandra sink](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/connectors/datastream/cassandra/); it has valuable features you haven't attempted to support, especially checkpointing.

As for your questions:

You can make `session` a member variable that can be initialized in `open` and used in `invoke`.

Flink will call the `invoke` method for every stream record coming into the sink. This record passed to invoke as the `value` parameter. You'll need to extract the fields like name, etc from that value.

You'll need to attach the sink to your job graph; overall it will end up being something like this:

```scala
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

env
  .addSource(source)
  ... // some processing
  .addSink(new CassandraAsSink())

env.execute()
```

By the way, there are [training lessons with examples and exercises](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/learn-flink/overview/) included in the Flink documentation to help you get started.

Comment: Yeah, I am aware, @David. I just wanted to practice the other ways. Could you please help me with that? Dominik answered my question but I guess he deleted it. Please guide me where I am going wrong.

Comment: I get your point @David. I just wanted to practice everything separately. That is the reason I am not including everything under a single piece. I know I am making it difficult for myself. About checkpointing, I will be implementing it for producer and consumer modules. However, by any chance can I implement it in the classes mentioned above?

Comment: Also, I have modified the question based on inputs. Could you please help me with that as well?

Comment: The invoke method of your sink doesn't have the correct signature for the situation where it's being used. Try changing it to have `value: String`.

Comment: Now, it says, method `'invoke'` overrides Nothing and the error mentioned in the post still persists.

Comment: What am I doing wrong over here? Is my calling part wrong or does something needs to be changed in the class?

Comment: Have your IDE generate the method stub for you, and then fill in the implementation.

Comment: ok let me try it

Comment: I resolved that. It was because I haven't specified any data type for RichSinkFunction. It should match with the value data type. Now when I used `val datastreamFromString:DataStream[String]=env.fromElements(data) // where data is string
        datastreamFromString.addSink(new CassandraAsSink())` It is not calling that class actually. Because I added some debugging statements in those 3 methods but it wasn't printed when I ran the program. What could be the problem? No errors as well.

Comment: I have also checked w.r.t my IDE that if I extend `ProcessFunction` it asks me to implement its methods. Whereas, when I extend `RichSinkFunction` it doesn't ask me to implement any methods. Why is it so?

Comment: Problem with `env` and creating datastream from a string. Modified my question accordingly.

Comment: David, could you please help me with this?

Comment: It's because `invoke` methods from `SinkFunction` have default implementations:
https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/sink/SinkFunction.java#L34:L51